# Using placeholders within Query loop blocks

Tags: wordpress, themes, gutenberg-blocks

I have template parts within my block theme that use Query loop blocks, how can I use placeholders that provide dynamic value to the Query loop blocks like so:

```
<!-- wp:query {"query":{"perPage":1,"postType":"{{PostType}}"}} -->
```

At the moment, all I see is a spinning icon on my block editor page

I have used several WP hooks, but none seems to be working.